# Making a list in sentinel loop (beginnger) PYTHON

Tags: python, list, loops, sentinel

after much google'ing and note searching I have yet to come upon an answer for making this List of mine work, if you do answer could you explain what I was doing wrong because this problem is determined to not let me work.
code:

```
def main():

    x = int(input("Enter a number (0 to stop) "))
    y = x
    l = []

    while x != 0:
        x = int(input("Enter a number (0 to stop) "))
        l = [x]
    print(l[x])   

main()
```

I thought I was supposed to initialize the list outside of the loop, and in the loop I thought it would take whatever X is inputted as and store it to later be printed out after it, but that wasn't the case. Any pointers?

Comment: Please ask your question - now it is not clear, what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to append to the list each time:

```
def main():
    x = int(input("Enter a number (0 to stop) "))
    l = [x] # add first x, we  will add to the is list  not reassign l inside the loop
    while x != 0:
        x = int(input("Enter a number (0 to stop) "))
        l.append(x) # append each time 
    print(l) # print all when user enters 0
```

`l = [x]` reassigns `l` to a list containing whatever the value of `x` is each time through the loop, to get all numbers you have to append to the list l initialised outside the loop.

You could also use `iter` with a sentinel value of "0":

```
def main():
    l  = []
    print("Enter a number (0 to stop) ")
    for x in iter(input,"0"):
        print("Enter a number (0 to stop) ")
        l.append(int(x))
    print(l)
```